Why did IHVs have never extended Direct3D through the facilities of COM on which it is based?
It is well known that Direct3D, unlike OpenGL, was never extensible in itself - a deliberate choice of Microsoft to favor the average user's expectations of predictable behavior and inherent compatibility. However, even this still hasn't stopped vendors from providing such functionality - see, for example, this summary by Aras Pranckevičius. And from this list it is also noticeable that all these extensions are implemented rather awkwardly - through the passing of custom arguments for conventional Direct3D API calls.
At the same time, Direct3D has always been based on the Component Object Model (COM), a technology that was conceptually designed to be extensible. So the idea naturally arises here that driver developers could implement interface extensions as custom COM objects installed into the system (I mean Windows).
But as far as I know, no Direct3D-enabled graphics solution has ever done this. So there must have been some discernible reason. But what exactly?
My best guess at the moment is that instead of real COM, DirectX actually used what is commonly called "lightweight COM", which among other things does not support system-wide components.

The simple answer is that it doesn't make sense economically. Supporting all the various feature levels that are currently abstracted through DirectX is expensive and time consuming enough without having to deal with vendor specific interfaces that are not part of the core DirectX interface. So the vast majority of developers do not need nor want such extensibility so nobody puts the effort into implementing it. Not allowing vendors to add their own interfaces sort-of keeps things under control. Economics at work.
Hardware developers face other problems. They have to support the libraries for decades at a time, they need qualified people to properly design and implement the extension libraries, they will be caught into a platform they cannot easily get out of, or do breaking changes without being seen as unreliable by the whole industry. But most of the problem boils down to not having a demand for this.
There are still sort-of extensions that you can use, like NVidia CUDA, which you can mix with DirectX code if you have the proper language bindings. However, such technologies are limited in scope, have unrelated interfaces, are hardware specific and will generally lock you into a specific hardware vendor which defeats the purpose of the unified DirectX interface in the first place. Applications that support multiple such hardware specific "extensions" are generally pretty expensive, use their own abstractions which will not need COM in any way, have large dedicated teams to properly test and are not the sort of bug ridden generic Steam game.
Those hacks you mentioned are generally vendors getting ahead of Microsoft. Like compute shaders being released some time after CUDA. Eventually these things make it into the core interface if used often enough.

The question is not about the motivation behind Microsoft - I understand that myself. I also understand why there are no extensions in the Metal API - because Apple is a vertically integrated corporation that wants to do everything themselves. What I do not understand is the motivation of the hardware developers, and their technical problems here, if any. Because it is well known that OpenGL's extensibility has always been perceived as a competitive advantage over Direct3D (and it was, in fact).

@cher-nov it is quite simple to deduce why hardware devs won't do it, they simply don't have a market for this, so they won't do it. They already covered the bits of the market that exists (CUDA and co) and that's fine. OpenGL works on a much smaller scale and it has to be extensible due to the nature of open source software and the lack of proper manufacturer support. There really is no comparison of the economics involved in openGL and those of DirectX.

Sorry, but I can't agree. Direct3D came out a few years after OpenGL, when the market for 3D solutions was already around.

Direct3D was targeted at gaming specifically, optimized as such and strictly versioned, so to allow game developers and graphics driver developers to do their part and make ends meet. Extensions would defeat the purpose of this industry standard. Direct3D version whatever should be just that, nothing less and nothing more.
